# Ambiguity when writing TStringList to TStream

Tags: c++, c++builder, tstringlist, tstream, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm working on a project that sends data between clients using streams. It implements a bunch of stream operators to support this. It worked fine in `C++ Builder 2010` but now that I'm moving the project to `C++ Builder 10 Seattle` I get a weird error.

In one function a `TStream` is created and data written to it

```
*pStream >>
        Version >>
        m_iPortNumber >>
        m_iHeartBeatTimeout >>
        m_iMaxToRead >>
        m_pIPAddressFilter >>
        m_iRetries;
```

`m_pIPAddressFilter` here is a `TStringList` and the error is related to that. It reads

> [bcc32 Error] E2015 Ambiguity between '>>(System::Classes::TStream
>   &,bool &) at Common\Streams.h:28' and '>>(System::Classes::TStream
>   &,System::Classes::TStrings *) at Common\Streams.h:42'

The implemented stream operators it's referring to look like this

```
PACKAGE TStream & operator <<(TStream &Stream, bool b)
{
    Stream.WriteBuffer(&b, sizeof(b));

    return Stream;
}

PACKAGE TStream & operator >>(TStream &Stream, bool &b)
{
    Stream.ReadBuffer(&b, sizeof(b));

    return Stream;
}

PACKAGE TStream & operator <<(TStream &Stream, TStrings *pList)
{
    int Count;
    int i;

    Stream << (Count=pList->Count);
    for (i=0; i<Count; i++)
        Stream << static_cast<WideString> (pList->Strings[i]);

    return Stream;
}

PACKAGE TStream & operator >>(TStream &Stream, TStrings *pList)
{
    AnsiString s;
    int Count;

    pList->Clear();
    Stream >> Count;
    while (Count--)
    {
        Stream >> s;
        pList->Add(s);
    }

    return Stream;
}
```

How can the compiler be confused by this and feel that it's ambiguous if the version taking a `bool` or the version taking `TStrings` should be used. `TStrings` is even a parent class of `TStringList` that is what is being written to the stream. As said, this worked fine in `C++ Builder 2010`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an `>>` operator defined specifically for `TStringList*`, so the compiler has to look for matching candidates to convert a `TStringList*` pointer to. Any pointer is implicitly convertible to a `bool`, and it would seem that the compiler considers a compiler-created temporary `bool` variable is a viable overload candidate, thus an ambiguity since `TStringList*` is convertible to both `TStrings*` and `bool&` (via a temp).

Change your `TStrings*` operators to take `TStrings&` parameter instead (which you should do anyway, don't pass object pointers to streaming operators), and then change `m_pIPAddressFilter` to `*m_pIPAddressFilter` when invoking the operators.  Then there will not be any ambiguity.

```
*pStream >>
    ...
    *m_pIPAddressFilter
    ...;
```

On a separate note, your `TStrings` operators seem to be inconsistent.  `<<` is streaming out `UnicodeString` values using an intermediate `WideString` (Why? And why are you using `static_cast`?).  Your `>>` operator is streaming in `UnicodeString` values using an intermediate `AnsiString` instead.  Those are different data conversions, so you are likely to corrupt data when non-ASCII characters are present.  You need to use consistent string types for both operators.  You should be streaming the `TStrings` values as-is using `String` variables, and then implement `String` operators to handle the actual streaming using a consistent format, like UTF-8, eg:

```
PACKAGE TStream & operator <<(TStream &Stream, String s)
{
    UTF8String utf = s;
    int Count = utf.Length();
    Stream << Count;
    Stream.WriteBuffer(utf.c_str(), Count);
    return Stream;
}

PACKAGE TStream & operator >>(TStream &Stream, String &s)
{
    UTF8String utf;
    int Count;
    Stream >> Count;
    s.SetLength(Count);
    Stream.ReadBuffer(utf.c_str(), Count);
    s = utf;
    return Stream;
}

PACKAGE TStream & operator <<(TStream &Stream, TStrings &pList)
{
    int Count = pList.Count;
    Stream << Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        Stream << pList.Strings[i];
    return Stream;
}

PACKAGE TStream & operator >>(TStream &Stream, TStrings &pList)
{
    pList.BeginUpdate();
    try
    {
        pList.Clear();

        String s;
        int Count;

        Stream >> Count;
        while (Count--)
        {
            Stream >> s;
            pList.Add(s);
        }
    }
    __finally {
        pList.EndUpdate();
    }

    return Stream;
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm not the original author of the code. It's roughly a million lines of code and I'm responsible for lifting it form the old 2010 version. I still find it strange that it compiles just fine in C++ Builder 2010 though. I actually did try to add a specific version for `TStringList` before posting here but it gave the exact same error. Regarding the WideStrings etc I think it's part of an earlier update when Unicode was introduced to the RTL. I'll give that an extra look to. I'll try references (lot of changes to code though) but I believed the compiler would sort it out even for pointers

Comment: You didn't say if you are compiling using the 32-bit "classic" compiler, or the new 32-bit clang compiler, or the 64-bit compiler.  I would suspect the classic and clang compilers act differently in this regard.

Comment: It's using the old classic BCC32 compiler. I hope to be able to have time to upgrade that someday to be able to take advantage on nice new C++ features, but the first step is to get it running on the old style BCC32 compiler that it was once crated for.... ohhh did I say "old"? I meant "classic" :P